# Importing CSS and Bootsrap in HTML code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I typed the below code in the  section of the HTML.  However, the CSS code and the bootstrap is not being recognised by the HTML.

```
<link href="C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Websites\public_html\Main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\bootstrap-3.3.4-dist\css\bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css">
```

What am I doing wrong pls?

Comment: Are you running this on a server or your local machine? There's also a big gap in your second link.

Comment: I'm running it on my local machine. it's my mistake that there is a big gap in the second link..I just edited it now

Comment: Try to the load bootstrap straight from the CDN. Replace your link with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

You can find this answer very easy by using google.

I would do the following. Create on your desktop a directory website. In this directory create a directory called "css", "js", "img". Create in the directory "website" index.html and enter this in the document:

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
```

Try making a container in your html file like:

```
<div class="container">
some text...
</div>
```

Use inspect element in firefox and you can see if your browser reads your css file.